# Integrating native widget with Ionic and Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, widget, native, capacitor

I'm trying to build a widget app (native) for Android and then integrate it with Ionic and Capacitor App. Should I treat it as a plugin or there is other way of integrating it?

I've created all native files and prepared the native version of widget but now I would like to add it to my Ionic project... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your widget as if you are working on a native Android app.
Capacitor plays no role here.

*if Android widgets are anything like iOS app extensions*